# How to Hide Value Based On CheckBox include Required when Checked (Drop-down box version included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, dropdownbox

I wish to display the text areas when the checkbox is checked and hide them when it is not.
The Interface can be run but the checkbox is not clickable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ifbroken').change(function() {
    if (this.checked)
      $('#dvchk').fadeIn('slow');
    else
      $('#dvchk').fadeOut('slow');
  })
});
```

```css
#dvchk {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <input type="checkbox" id="ifbroken">
  <label for="ifborken">If Broken</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12" id="dvchk">
  <label for="Problem">Problem</label></br>
  </br>
  <textarea name="Problem" style="width:600px; height:200px;"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12" id="dvchk">
  <label for="ActionTaken">Action Taken</label></br>
  </br>
  <textarea name="ActionTaken" style="width:600px; height:200px;"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12" id="dvchk">
  <label for="BuyOff">Buy Off</label></br>
  </br>
  <textarea name="BuyOff" style="width:600px; height:200px;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: It is clickable.

Comment: I don't know, when I run through my interface, it's not working

Comment: Try different web browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple identical IDs and invalid HTML and too many jQuery files loaded

This works

I changed the IDs to class, fixed the typo in the label and the invalid `</br>`

I also moved the inline style into the stylesheet

```js
function toggleField() {
  $fld = $(".dvchk").find(":input").prop("required", this.checked);

  if (this.checked) $('.dvchk').fadeIn('slow'); // there is alas no fadeToggle(boolean)
  else $('.dvchk').fadeOut('slow');
}
$(function() {
  $('#ifbroken').on("click", toggleField)
});
```

```css
.dvchk {
  display: none
}

textarea {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <input type="checkbox" id="ifbroken">
    <label for="ifbroken">If Broken</label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field col s12 dvchk">
    <label for="Problem">Problem</label><br /><br />
    <textarea name="Problem"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field col s12 dvchk">
    <label for="ActionTaken">Action Taken</label><br /><br />
    <textarea name="ActionTaken"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field col s12 dvchk">
    <label for="BuyOff">Buy Off</label><br /><br />
    <textarea name="BuyOff"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input class="dvchk" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, If I wish to make the hidden attributes to be required once it is visible. It doesn't work when I try to write this `$('.dvchk').fadeOut('slow');
                         $('.dvchk').prop('required', false);`

Comment: Is it correct if I write like this?
`$(function() {
                $('#ifbroken').change(function() {
                    if (this.value == 'Yes'){
                         $('.dvchk').fadeIn('slow');
                         $('.dvchk').attr("required");
                         } 
                    else if (this.value == 'No'){
                         $('.dvchk').fadeOut('slow');
                         $('.dvchk').removeAttr("required");
                         }
                });  
                });`

Comment: Strange, it still doesn't work. The required areas still be able to skip even though it is left blank

Comment: Thank you very much, what if one of the text areas I've changed to a drop down box, is there anywhere I need to modify?

Comment: Fixed all. I did not set the input fields to required but the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Based on @mplungjan 's answer, I've also developed a drop box version too!

JavaScript Function:

```
function toggleField() {
  $fld = $(".dvchk").find(":input").prop("required", this.value =='Yes');

  if (this.value == 'Yes') $('.dvchk').fadeIn('slow'); // there is alas no 
  fadeToggle(boolean)
  else $('.dvchk').fadeOut('slow');
 }
$(function() {
  $('#ifbroken').change(toggleField)
});
```

HTML Drop-Box:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-field col s12">
 <label for="IfBroken">If Broken</label></br></br>
  <select name="IfBroken" id="ifbroken" required> 
   <option value="">Choose</option> 
   <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
   <option value="No">No</option>
  </select> 
</div>
```